# does these 2 ways of querying equivalent?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, mybatis, spring-mybatis

I'm a Spring backend learner, currently want to query some data from mysql. What I want is just a field from table.(I want `categoryName` in `category`).

First, I was using LambdaQueryWrapper. I wrote

```
categoryLambdaQueryWrapper.eq(Category::getId, categoryId);
Category category = categoryService.getOne(categoryLambdaQueryWrapper);
```

But category values `null` occasionally.

Then, I changed to simply using getById method in categoryService, everything worked fine.

```
Category category = categoryService.getById(categoryId);
```

I confused, is there anything difference between the 2 ways of querying? I thought they were equivalent before. Thank you for everyone who can help me.

Answer (score -1):

The difference is that `categoryService.getOne(categoryLambdaQueryWrapper)` returns a single entity that matches the conditions specified in the lambda query wrapper, or null if no such entity exists.

On the other hand, `categoryService.getById(categoryId)` directly queries the database for the entity with the specified categoryId, returns the entity if it exists, or throws an exception if it doesn't.

So if you want to ensure that a category exists before processing it, it's better to use `categoryService.getById(categoryId)`.